# How Can I create Interface for ItemClickListener in Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, adapter

I am new to Android & Kotlin. I want to click my row and intent it to other activity. That's why I  tried to create an interface in my Adapter but it does not work. How can I create it?

My adapter code:

```
class NoteAdapter(private val titleTextArray: ArrayList<String>, private val imageArray: ArrayList<String>) : RecyclerView.Adapter<NoteAdapter.NoteHolder>() {

    class NoteHolder (view: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view) {
      
            var recyclerTitleText: TextView ?= null
            var recyclerImageView: ImageView ?= null

        init {
            recyclerTitleText = view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerTitleText)
            recyclerImageView = view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerImage)
        }
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): NoteHolder {
        val inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
        val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.recycler_row, parent, false)
        return NoteHolder(view)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: NoteHolder, position: Int) {
        holder.recyclerTitleText?.text = titleTextArray[position]
        Picasso.get().load(imageArray[position]).into(holder.recyclerImageView)

    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return titleTextArray.size
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With Kotlin, you could to use a lambda (higher order function) to fetch the user clicks in the holder.  For example, a base approach could be the next:

```
class YourAdapter(
    private val listener: (String) -> Unit
) : RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder>() {

    private val yourDataList = emptyList<String>()

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        val view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.compound_checkbox_terms_layout, parent, false)
        return YourViewHolder(view)
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        TODO("not implemented") //To change body of created functions use File | Settings | File Templates.
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        TODO("not implemented") //To change body of created functions use File | Settings | File Templates.
    }


    private inner class YourViewHolder(view: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view) {
        
        init {
            if (adapterPosition != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION) {
                val selectedData = yourDataList[adapterPosition]
                listener.invoke(selectedData)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Pass the activity context to the adapter from Activity so it can launch intent

Activity Code :

```
mAdapter = new CustomAdapter(this, imageArray, ArrayList);
```

Adapter Code :

```
class NoteAdapter(private val titleTextArray: ArrayList, private val imageArray: ArrayList, private val context : Context) : RecyclerView.Adapter<NoteAdapter.NoteHolder>() {
    class NoteHolder (view: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view) {
        var recyclerTitleText: TextView?= null
        var recyclerImageView : ImageView?= null
        init {
            recyclerTitleText = view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerTitleText)
            recyclerImageView = view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerImage)
        }
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): NoteHolder {

        val inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
        val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.recycler_row, parent, false)
        return NoteHolder(view)

    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: NoteHolder, position: Int) {

        holder.recyclerTitleText?.text = titleTextArray[position]
        Picasso.get().load(imageArray[position]).into(holder.recyclerImageView)
        holder.recyclerImageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(context, NesneTani.class);
                context.startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {

        return titleTextArray.size

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create an Interface to catch the click event. (position is optional)

```
interface OnItemClickListener {
fun onItemClick(position: Int)
```

}

add OnItemClickListener as a parameter in your Adapter class

```
class NoteAdapter(
private val titleTextArray: ArrayList<String>,
private val imageArray: ArrayList<String>,
private val listener: OnItemClickListener
) : RecyclerView.Adapter<NoteAdapter.NoteHolder>()
```

Then do below inside onBindViewHolder

```
 override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: NoteHolder, position: Int) {
 listener.onItemClick(position)
}
```

now inside your activity, implement the OnItemClickListener

```
class ActivityName implements OnItemClickListener{}
```

and while initiating adapter, do this

```
mAdapter = new CustomAdapter(this, imageArray, ArrayList);
```

Then inside the overridden method do what you want

```
override fun onItemClick(position: Int) {
//start the activity you want.
}
```

Comment: The code in OnBindViewHolder, ıt shows me the error about override and position.

Comment: can you tell me what is the exact issue?

Comment: The error explanation is : for position, it wants the Arraylist,     for override, ıt is not applicable to local function. I tried to solve but does not work. Thanks

Comment: I tried executing the same code, but I did not face any issue inside onBindViewHolder. Can you please execute your code and post the logs in your question? it will help understand it.